# Android - inflate TabHost into TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have successfully displayed tabHost, I have three tabs now. I was trying to inflate into one of them another tabHost, but I wasn't successfull. Is it actually possible to inflate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, I think its not good idea, try to add tabhost in the tabcontent of desired tabhost in which u want to add the subtab or u can add tabhost in the layout which opens in desired tab.

Comment: Yea, I mean it like that. I now have tabs A, B and C. And in tabcontent of A I want to display another TabHost. Up to now, I don't know, how to achieve this.

Comment: If you displaying activity in the tabcontent of A then u need to add tabhost in the activity layout file..

Comment: no, I am displaying here linear layout now, without defining another activity

Comment: Ok, then u define another tablayout in separate layout file and add include statement in tabcontent in original tab layout.

Comment: As far as I know, Tablayout lies in TabHost, but this I cannot inlfate into my layout (I need it to be done dynamically). So I know it theoretically, but I am not able to transfer it into source code.

Comment: Also check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907374/how-to-create-a-sub-tabs-in-android

Comment: Thanks but this is still not covering my problem